# using a RecursiveDirectoryIterator to match * subfolders

Tags: php

How can I use * inside a RecursiveDirectoryIterator?

Lets imagine I have files like this:

```
./files/ABC123/uriewo/bob/file1.txt
./files/ABC123/uriewo/bob/file2.txt
./files/ABC123/uriewo/John/file1.txt
./files/ABC123/t3t35/bob/file1.txt
./files/ABC123/urihfgewo/Terry/file1.txt
```

I want to match all files in the `ABC123` directory and the `bob` directory. i.e.

`./files/ABC123/*/bob/`

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./files/ABC123/*/bob/', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
    );
```

isn't allowed since it can't match the `*` - how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php) isn't specifically designed to filter directories based on the pattern you provide. Hence, this won't work.

---

However, you can use the [`GlobIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php) iterator class to suit your needs by passing in a [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) pattern to it's constructor and then iterating over all the matched files like below:

```
<?php

$it = new GlobIterator(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ABC123/*/bob/*', FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO);

while($it->valid()){
    echo $it->current()->getRealPath(),PHP_EOL;
    $it->next();
}
```